# Using operators with certain types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, operators

I am trying to do the equation answer < 10 && answer > 0.9.
Then if this is true do something.

```
if (answer < 10 && answer > 0.9)
                        {

                        }
```

But I get the error "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'

In my code,

```
var y = 1000000;
var answer = x*y;
```

X is equal to whatever the user inputs in a text box.

I don't know where I am getting double from to be honest. Maybe it is what my answer becomes if it becomes too large? And how can I make the if statement work>

Comment: Your literal `0.9` has type `double`.  Try `0.9m` if you want to do calculations in decimal.  Or change the data type of `x`, since that is causing `answer` to have type `decimal` and could be `double` (There's a tradeoff between accuracy and range here)

Comment: It is not answer to your question, but it will clearify the sentence provided by @BenVoigt "(There's a tradeoff between accuracy and range here) ". watch the link of jon skeet prsentation title "Back to basics: the mess we've made of our fundamental data types" 

www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3nPJ-yK-LU.

Answer (score 0):

The var "answer" is of the type int and you're trying to compare 10(of type int) and 0.9(of type double)

Try:

```
var y = 1000000;
var answer = Convert.ToDouble(x*y);
```

and

```
if (answer < 10.0 && answer > 0.9)
```

and i think that will work :)

Comment: I don't think that `answer` is of type `int`, since the error message mentioned `decimal`.